# Parsing JSON in PHP to extract lat/lon

Tags: php, json, parsing

I need to parse this JSON using PHP

```
[{
    "options": {
        "allowUTurn": false
    },
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 44.91138,
        "lng": 7.671783
    },
    "name": "Corso Vinovo, Carignano, TO, Piemont, Italy",
    "_initHooksCalled": true
}, {
    "options": {
        "allowUTurn": false
    },
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 44.909979,
        "lng": 7.676234
    },
    "name": "Il Tempio del Pane, Corso Cesare Battisti, Carignano, TO, Piemont, Italy",
    "_initHooksCalled": true
}, {
    "options": {
        "allowUTurn": false
    },
    "latLng": {
        "lat": 44.907805,
        "lng": 7.674952
    },
    "name": "Banca Intesa, Via Ferdinando Salotto, Carignano, TO, Piemont, Italy",
    "_initHooksCalled": true
}]
```

to extract the coordinates in lat / lon.

What have I to use after

```
echo $wayPoints->?????
```

and how I create a for cicle to extract all the coordinates?

Any help will be appreciated!!Thank you!

Cesare

EDIT: a code sample (note that the JSON come from a POST parameter ...)

```
<?php
  echo "Waypoints ...</br>";
  echo "</br>";
  echo $_POST['wayPoints'];
  $wayPoints = $_POST['wayPoints'];

  $json = json_decode($wayPoints);

  foreach($json as $f){
    echo $f['latLng']['lat'];
    echo $f['latLng']['lng'];
  }
?>
```

so should be more clear ... (the code NOT working ...)

Thank you again ...

EDIT 2: this code work !!!

```
<?php
  echo "Waypoints ...</br>";
  echo "</br>";
  echo $_POST['wayPoints'];
  $wayPoints = $_POST['wayPoints'];

  $json = json_decode($wayPoints, true);

  foreach($json as $f){
    echo "</br>";
    echo $f['latLng']['lat'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $f['latLng']['lng'];
    echo "</br>";      }
?>
```

the output is

```
44.91138
7.671783

44.909979
7.676234

44.907805
7.674952
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will convert your json object into an associative array, then iterate with foreach.

```
//use json_decode in associative mode
$decoded = json_decode($json, true);

//Your object is now an array called $decoded
//Your locations are subarrays of $decoded
//The co-ords are subarrays of each $locationArray
foreach($decoded as $locationArray)
{
    echo "The co-ordinates for {$locationArray['name']} are: {$locationArray['latLng']['lat']},{$locationArray['latLng']['lng']}" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to do `$file = json_decode()`
and then the file you get just add to foreach:

```
foreach($file as $f){
echo $f['latLng']['lat'];
echo $f['latLng']['lng'];
}
```

Comment: note that this answer only works if you pass `true` as the 2nd parameter for `json_decode`

Comment: Thanks Marko  ... I've tried to put a small code sample in my original request .... I've tried your suggestion but It's not working ... :-)

Comment: @Cesare yeah, i forgot to mention `true` parameter in `json_decode`